# getting error 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am new in python but not getting same code is run core file but not work with scrapy

```
'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

  File "/root/Desktop/crawler/webcrawler/webcrawler/spiders/regex.py", line 161, in colorz
    test  = test + (p.coords[v] - clusters[i].center.coords[v]) ** 2    
exceptions.TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: One of `p.coords` or `clusters` or `clusters[i].center.coords` is an integer, not a sequence. Can you please include the relevant code so we can suggest a fix?

Comment: _"but not getting same code is run core file"_. I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I am using this  http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-and-k-means-to-find-the-dominant-colors-in-images/  when i run run it it's working proper but when i add it on scrapy i am getting this error

Comment: still confusing. Can you share your code ? What it is the workflow ? Downloading and after processing in item pipelines ?